# Unix socket hangs on recv, until I place/remove a breakpoint anywhere

Tags: c++, sockets

[**TL;DR version**: the code below hangs indefinitely on the second recv() call both in Release and Debug mode. In Debug, if I place or remove a breakpoint anywhere in the code, it makes the execution continue and everything behaves normally]

I'm coding a simple client-server communication using UNIX sockets. The server is in C++ while the client is in python. The connection (TCP socket on localhost) gets established no problem, but when it comes to receiving data on the server side, it hangs on the recv function. Here is the code where the problem happens:

```
bool server::readBody(int csock) // csock is the socket filedescriptor
{
    int bytecount;

    // protobuf-related variables
    google::protobuf::uint32 siz;
    kinMsg::request message;
    // if the code is working, client will send false
    // I initialize at true to be sure that the message is actually read
    message.set_endconnection(true); 

    // First, read 4-characters header for extracting data size
    char buffer_hdr[5];
    if((bytecount = recv(csock, buffer_hdr, 4, MSG_WAITALL))== -1)
        ::std::cerr << "Error receiving data "<< ::std::endl;
    buffer_hdr[4] = '\0';
    siz = atoi(buffer_hdr);

    // Second, read the data. The code hangs here !!
    char buffer [siz];
    if((bytecount = recv(csock, (void *)buffer, siz, MSG_WAITALL))== -1)
        ::std::cerr << "Error receiving data " <<  errno  << ::std::endl;

    //Finally, process the protobuf message
    google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buffer,siz);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream coded_input(&ais);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit msgLimit = coded_input.PushLimit(siz);
    message.ParseFromCodedStream(&coded_input);
    coded_input.PopLimit(msgLimit);

    if (message.has_endconnection())
          return !message.endconnection();

    return false;
}
```

As can be seen in the code, the protocol is such that the client will first send the number of bytes in the message in a 4-character array, followed by the protobuf message itself. The first recv call works well and does not hang. Then, the code hangs on the second recv call, which should be recovering the body of the message.

Now, for the interesting part. When run in Release mode, the code hangs indefinitely and I have to kill either the client or the server. It does not matter whether I run it from my IDE (qtcreator), or from the CLI after a clean build (using cmake/g++).

When I run the code in Debug mode, it also hangs at the same recv() call. **Then, if I place or remove a breakpoint ANYWHERE in the code (before or after that line of code), it starts again and works perfectly**  : the server receives the data, and reads the correct message.endconnection() value before returning out of the readBody function. The breakpoint that I have to place to trigger this behavior is not necessarily trigerred. Since the readBody() function is in a loop (my C++ server waits for requests from the python client), at the next iteration, the same behavior happens again, and I have to place or remove a breakpoint anywhere in the code, which is not necessarily triggered, in order to go past that recv() call. The loop looks like this:

```
bool connection = true;

// server waiting for client connection
if (!waitForConnection(connectionID)) std::cerr << "Error accepting connection" << ::std::endl;

// main loop
while(connection)
{
    if((bytecount = recv(connectionID, buffer, 4, MSG_PEEK))== -1)
    {
        ::std::cerr << "Error receiving data "<< ::std::endl;
    }
    else if (bytecount == 0)
         break;

    try
    {
        if(readBody(connectionID))
        {
            sendResponse(connectionID);
        }

        // if client is requesting disconnection, break the while(true)
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Disconnection requested by client. Exiting ..." << std::endl;
            connection = false;
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Erro receiving message from client" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Finally, as you can see, when the program returns from readBody(), it sends back another message to the client, which processes it and prints in the standard output (python code working, not shown because the question is already long enough). From this last behavior, I can conclude that the protocol and client code are OK. I tried to put sleep instructions at many points to see whether it was a timing problem, but it did not change anything.

I searched all over Google and SO for a similar problem, but did not find anything. Help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not use any flags. Call `recv` with `0` for the flags or just use `read` instead of `recv`.

You are requesting the socket for data that is not there. The `recv` expects 10 bytes, but the client only sent 6. The `MSG_WAITALL` states clearly that the call should block until 10 bytes are available in the stream.

If you dont use any flags, the call will succeed with a `bytecount` at 6, which is the exact same effect than with `MSG_DONTWAIT`, without the potential side effects of non-blocking calls.

I did the test on the github project, it works.

Comment: Interesting .. but not complete ! 

Actually, I changed the order of the recv calls on the server when writing my "solution", and I made a typo, forgetting to remove a +4 somewhere. That's why the code was asking for 10 bytes and waiting for the 4 next. 

However, that's not the behavior of the code which is here. It clearly is reading 4 bytes for the header and then 6 for the message, as it should..

I'll make a branch on the github with a version reproducing the exact problem and post it here when it's done

Comment: OK, after some more investigation, both solutions (without a flag and with the MSG_WAITALL) work fine. The issue was on the client side in python. To simplify, just with the header, a message sent like this in python (see code below) will be received with a bytecount of 2, instead of 4, in the C++ server. Of course, a blocking recv() call expecting 4 bytes keeps blocking. I'm not sure this is the expected behavior ... 

`length = 4
client_socket.sendall(str(length).zfill(4))`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace MSG_WAITALL by MSG_DONTWAIT in the recv() calls. It now works fine. To summarize, it makes the recv() calls non blocking, which makes the whole code work fine.

However, this still raises many questions, the first of which being: why was it working with this weird breakpoint changing thing ?

If the socket was blocking in the first place, one could assume that it is because there is no data on the socket. Let's assume both situations here :

1. There is no data on the socket, which is the reason why the blocking recv() call was not working. Changing it to a non blocking recv() call would then, in the same situation, trigger an error. If not, the protobuf deserialization would afterwards fail trying to deserialize from an empty buffer. But it does not ...
2. There is data on the socket. Then, why on earth would it block in the first place ?

Obviously there is something that I don't get about sockets in C, and I'd be very happy if somebody has an explanation for this behavior !

Comment: And to be complete, here is a full working code using a toy example, if you want to experiment: https://github.com/benoitrosa/Cpp_python_protobuf